# why sample's size is difference when concatenate two dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dimension

I transformed separately training set and test set to get dummies for categorical features with `pandas.get_dummies()`.
So the dimension difference occurred because of categorical differences in the training set and the test set.
I tried to equalize the dimension.
But the problem below occurred.
Why is the sample size different when concatenating two dataframes?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is not default `RangeIndex` in `X_train.index`, so need create it before `concat`:

```
X_train = X_train.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Another solution is add parameter `index` for same indices in both `DataFrame`s:

```
diff_df2 = pd.Dataframe(np.zeros((X_train.shape[0], len(diff_dummy2))), 
                        columns=diff_dummy2,
                        index= X_train.index)
```

Comment: Awesome! your solution is very good!
I solved the problem.
thank you!

Comment: @김정석 - Supeer, glad can help!

Comment: `X_train.index` was `Int64Index` and `diff_df2.index` was `RangeIndex`.
I think I'll have to study index type of dataframe.